# How to replace text in a ruby string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, loops

I am trying to write a very simple method in Ruby which takes a string and an array of words and checks if the string contains any of the words and if it does it replaces them with their uppercase.

I made an attempt but its not great due to my level of Ruby skills.

```
def(my_words,my_sentence)
  #split the sentence up into an array of words
  my_sentence_words =  my_sentence.split(/\W+/)
  #nested loop that checks the words array for each brand 
  my_sentence_words.each do |i|
    my_words.each do |i|
      #if it finds a brand in the words and sets them to be uppercase
      if my_words[i] == my_sentence_words[i]
        my_sentence_words[i] == my_sentence_words[i].up.case
      end
    end
  end

  #put the words array into one string
  words.each do |i|
    new_sentence = ("" + my_sentence_words[i]) + " "
  end
end
```

I am getting: `can't convert string into integer error`

Comment: For one thing you are using `i` twice, use `j` for the inner loop. Second, you didn't give your function a name. List the full error.

Comment: provide meaningful example data

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: As you gain experience with Ruby you'll find that you don't loop on indices nearly as often as you may be accustomed with `C` and the like.  You'll be relying more on `each` and the numerous methods in the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html)  "mixin" (module), nearly all of which are implemented with `each`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def convert(mywords,sentence)
 regex = /#{mywords.join("|")}/i
 sentence.gsub(regex) { |m| m.upcase }
end
convert(%W{ john james jane }, "I like jane but prefer john")
#=> "I like JANE but prefer JOHN"
```

Comment: Note `convert(%W{ JANE }, "I like JANE") => "I like "` and `convert(%W{ JANE }, "I like jane") => "I like jane"`.  You need to add `/i` and remove `!`.

Comment: Be careful with `/#{mywords.join("|")}/i`. It will create a pattern that allows sub-string matches, not whole-word matches. `/\b#{mywords.join("|")}\b/i` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

This will work better. It loops through the brands, searches for each, and replaces with the uppercase version.

```
brands = %w(sony toshiba)
sentence = "This is a sony. This is a toshiba."

brands.each do |brand|
  sentence.gsub!(/#{brand}/i, brand.upcase)
end
```

Results in the string.

```
"This is a SONY. This is a TOSHIBA."
```

For those who like Ruby foo!

```
sentence.gsub!(/#{brands.join('|')}/i) { |b| b.upcase }
```

And in a function

```
def capitalize_brands(brands, sentence)
  sentence.gsub(/#{brands.join('|')}/i) { |b| b.upcase }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, also one other question for example if I am using this code in my rails app and wanted to take a string and replace a wordd with a link to a url so it would go to brands/sony etc. How could I put a link inside of a string?

Comment: Just use `link_to b.upcase, 'YOUR_URL'`

Comment: mutt, does `link_to` require a `require`?

Comment: It shouldn't if you are using it in a helper.

Comment: It appears to be from `ActionView::Helpers`, which I presume is used with Rails.  That's what I meant about a `require`, as the question is not tagged with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `i` doesn't start from `0` as you expected, in `each` method `i` is an element of array, and has string type, it's a first word from your sentence:

```
my_sentence_words = ["word"]
my_sentence_words.each do |i|
  puts i.length #=> 4
  puts i.type   #=> String
  puts i        #=> word
end
```

So you try to call `my_sentence_words[word]` instead of `my_sentence_words[0]`. You can try method `each_index` that passes `index` of element instead of element itself`:

```
def check(str, *arr)
  upstr = str.split(' ')
  upstr.eachindex do |i|       #=> i is index
    arr.each_index do  |j|  
      upstr[i].upcase! if upstr[i] == arr[j]        
    end
  end
  upstr
end

check("This is my sentence", "day", "is", "goal", "may", "my")
#=>["This", "IS", "MY", "sentence"]
```