# How do I replace words in a string based on words in an Array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how would I do the following? I tried doing this gsub but I can't figure out what really efficient if strings_to_highlight array is large. Cheers!

```
  string = "Roses are red, violets are blue"

  strings_to_highlight = ['red', 'blue']

  # ALGORITHM HERE

  resulting_string = "Roses are (red), violets are (blue)"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace text in a ruby string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502165/how-to-replace-text-in-a-ruby-string)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". We'd like to see your effort toward solving the problem, not just a framework with "# ALGORITHM HERE". We're here to help fix problems with your code, not write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash for making substitutions.

```
strings_to_highlight = ['red', 'blue']
```

First construct the hash.

```
h = strings_to_highlight.each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
  h[s] = "(#{s})"
  ss = "#{s[0].swapcase}#{s[1..-1]}"
  h[ss] = "(#{ss})"
end
  #=> {"red"=>"(red)", "Red"=>"(Red)", "Blue"=>"(Blue)", "blue"=>"(blue)"}
```

Next define a default proc for it:

```
h.default_proc = ->(h,k) { k }
```

so that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns `k` (e.g., `h["cat"] #=> "cat"`).

Ready to go!

```
string = "Roses are Red, violets are blue"

string.gsub(/[[[:alpha:]]]+/, h)
 => "Roses are (Red), violets are (blue)"
```

This should be relatively efficient as only one pass through the string is needed and hash lookups are very fast.

Answer (score 5):

`Regexp` has a helpful [`union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) function for combining regular expressions together. Stick with regexp until you have a performance problem:

```
string = "Roses are red, violets are blue"
strings_to_highlight = ['red', 'blue']

def highlight(str, words)
  matcher = Regexp.union words.map { |w| /\b(#{Regexp.escape(w)})\b/ }
  str.gsub(matcher) { |word| "(#{word})" }
end

puts highlight(string, strings_to_highlight)
```

Comment: Great use of `Regexp.union` here, but do try and link through to the current version of the documentation, and also using the `[...](...)` notation to avoid ugly bare URLs.

Comment: Be really careful with `Regexp.union words.map { |w| /\b(#{Regexp.escape(w)})\b/ } # => /(?-mix:\b(red)\b)|(?-mix:\b(blue)\b)/`. The pattern generated has potential pitfalls in it. Plus the pattern generated could be a lot more simple.

Comment: @theTinMan what are the pitfalls? The resulting regexp is overly complicated because it preserves the options of all the component patterns (the ?-mix means m,i,and x are all not enabled for each sub-pattern), but I'd still rather use Regexp#union over building a big pattern with regexp string interpolation and literal "|".

Answer (score 4):

```
strings_to_highlight = ['red', 'blue']
string = "Roses are red, violets are blue"

strings_to_highlight.each { |i| string.gsub!(/\b#{i}\b/, "(#{i})")}
```

Comment: What happens when `string = 'redeem'`?

Comment: give it a try, but I would assume that you would get (red)eem

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII please fix your answer so that it works as required.

Comment: This works but gets geometrically slower on longer arrays and longer strings.

Comment: Hey @sagarpandya82 so for as I can tell the requested features are an algorithm that replaces sub strings in a string that match strings in an array and my solution does that. What were you referring to?

Comment: @mu is too short fixed the false positive issue

Comment: ok now it works properly with your edit. I removed downvote and given upvote:)

Comment: Thanks for the motivation :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
string = "Roses are red, violets are blue"
strings_to_highlight = ['red', 'blue']

string.gsub(/\b(#{Regexp.union(strings_to_highlight).source})\b/) { |s| "(#{s})" } # => "Roses are (red), violets are (blue)"
```

Here's how it breaks down:

```
/\b(#{Regexp.union(strings_to_highlight).source})\b/ # => /\b(red|blue)\b/
```

It's important to use `source` when embedding a pattern. Without it results in:

```
/\b(#{Regexp.union(strings_to_highlight)})\b/ # => /\b((?-mix:red|blue))\b/
```

and that `(?-mix:...)` part can cause problems if you don't understand what it means in regex-ese. The Regexp documentation explains the flags but failing to do this can lead to a really hard to diagnose bug if you're not aware of the problem.

`\b` tells the engine to match words, not substrings. Without that you could end up with:

```
string = "Fred, bluette"
strings_to_highlight = ['red', 'blue']
string.gsub(/(#{Regexp.union(strings_to_highlight).source})/) { |s| "(#{s})" } 
# => "F(red), (blue)tte"
```

Using a block with `gsub` allows us to perform calculations on the matched values.